# safari browser - ":after" pseudo element still visible without content

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, safari

I have the following style

```
  .c-breadcrumb-item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgba($base-color, 0.5);

    &:not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
      .c-breadcrumb-link {
        color: rgba($base-color, 0.5);
        cursor: pointer;

        &:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
        &:active {
          color: $base-color;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      }

      &:after {
        content: '>';
        padding: 0 4px;
      }
    }

    &:nth-last-child(2) {
      animation: fadeIn 0.4s;
      .c-breadcrumb-link {
        color: $sky-blue;
      }
    }
  }
```

the initial state is as expected without the second after element from last

```
<div class="c-breadcrumb" data-test="c-breadcrumb">
  <span class="c-breadcrumb-item"><a class="c-breadcrumb-link">All</a></span>
  **<span class="c-breadcrumb-item"><a class="c-breadcrumb-link">Region number 2</a></span>**
  <span class="c-padding-simulate"></span>
</div>
```

but the issue is when I remove one breadcrumb item,the after element still visible with box-sizing: border-box

```
<div class="c-breadcrumb" data-test="c-breadcrumb">
  **<span class="c-breadcrumb-item"><a class="c-breadcrumb-link">All</a></span>**
  <span class="c-padding-simulate"></span>
</div>
```

please help me to solve it

Comment: what you need output add screen shot

Comment: Are you saying this only happens on IOS? I made [a codepen](https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/LYEdyPG), but I don't have an iPhone, so I can't conclude anything.

Comment: do you have mac? it's happens in safari browser

Comment: @GiladTamam Sorry, no Mac, no iPad. I've got Linux at home and Windows at work and a bunch of Android devices and an old Symbian phone, but that's it.